# H2 does not fetch fields with relationship

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, h2, spring-test

I'm writing test for getting correct data from database based on queries.

My application-test.properties for test profile are:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.data=data-test.sql
spring.datasource.schema=schema-test.sql

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

schema-test.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE main_table (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE main_table_field (
    main_table_id INT NOT NULL,
    field VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (main_table_id, field),
    FOREIGN KEY (main_table_id) REFERENCES main_table(id)
);
```

data-test.sql

```
INSERT INTO main_table VALUES (1, 'name1');

INSERT INTO main_table_field VALUES (1, 'field1');
INSERT INTO main_table_field VALUES (1, 'field2');
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class MainTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> field;
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface MainTableRepository extends JpaRepository<MainTable, Long> {}
```

Test:

```
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MainTableDataTest {

    @Autowired
    private MainTableRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        MainTable item = repository.findById(1L).get();
        assertEquals(item.getField().size(), 1);
    }
}
```

Test failed because of size of `field` is 0. The list is empty. What's wrong here? I inserted values throug my data-test.sql. I checked and i can get this row by repository but why related list is empty?

Situation applies only for test. While application is running on same data and schema then related list if filled.